# Java specific exercise with Collections.sort

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I have this `Test` class and I have to write the others classes code in order to pass the asserts.
That's the `Test` class:

```or-tag
import java.util.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Book javabook = new Book("Learn Java",150);
        Book cbook = new Book("C",120); 
        Book[] books = new Book[] {javabook, cbook};

        Library lib = new Library(books);
        assert(lib.pages() == 270);

        List l = lib;
        assert(l.size() == 2);

        Collections.sort(l); 

        assert(l.get(0) == cbook);
        assert(l.get(1) == javabook);
    }
}
```

I started making the Book class, here is my implementation:

```or-tag
public class Book implements Comparable
{
    private String name;
    private int pages;

    public Book(String name, int pages)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.pages = pages;
    }

    public int getPages()
    {
        return this.pages;
    }

    public int compareTo(Object obj)
    {
        if(this == obj) return 0;
        else
        {
            Book x = (Book) obj;
            return this.pages - x.pages;
        }
    }
}
```

Then I wrote the Library class:

```or-tag
import java.util.*;

public class Library extends ArrayList
{
    ArrayList a;

    public Library(Book[] b)
    {
        a = new ArrayList(b.length);
        for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
        {
            a.add(b[i]);
        }
    }

    public int pages()
    {
        int p = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<a.size(); i++)
        {
            p += ( (Book) a.get(i) ).getPages();
        }   
        return p;
    }

    public int size()
    {
        return a.size();
    }

    public Object get(int i)
    {
        return a.get(i);
    }
}
```

I think the problem is on the `Library` class, seems like the `Collections.sort` doesn't work and I can't pass the asserts after the call of the method sort in the Test class! I can't figure out what's the problem on my code, can someone help me please?

Remember: **I have to make my code in order to pass the `assert`s.**
I'm not sure about my Library implementation in order to make this line on the Test work:

```or-tag
List l = lib;
```

Not sure about the ArrayList extension.

P.S. I know it's better to use generic types but I mustn't use them for this exercise. Without using them I get some warnings, just ignore them.

Comment: `Collections.sort` uses some methods like iterators, that your `Library` class does not delegate to `a`. What might confuse you is that there are two arraylist states involved for each Library--the one from extending `ArrayList`, and the one from `a`.

Comment: So the problem is that my class doesn't implements iterators methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of the `Library` class is indeed wrong - it shouldn't **have** a list of `Book`s, it should **be** a list of `Book`s - that's why it extends an `ArrayList`:

```
public class Library extends ArrayList<Book> {
    // Note: no additional data members.
    // The Library is already a List<Book>:

    public Library(Book[] b) {
        super(Arrays.asList(b));
    }

    public int pages() {
        int p = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < size(); i++) {
            p += get(i).getPages();
        }
        return p;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This solution is helpful for me, never thought it was so simple, but I didn't know the `Arrays.asList` method so I think I couldn't get this kind of solution by myself. Thanks again.